# Clases dinámicas en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo en mi proyecto laravel en la carpeta views otra carpeta layouts en la que tengo un archivo aplicacion.blade.php donde tengo el header y el footer de mi proyecto, la etiqueta html title la tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
<title>@yield('title','Mi Primer Proyecto')</title>
```

Cuando creo una pagina nueva envío el contenido al title de la siguiente forma:

```
@extends('layouts.aplicacion')<br>
@section('title')<br>
Home<br>
@endsection
```

ejemplo de la pagina home.blade.php

Lo que necesito es crear en la etiqueta nav una clase dinámica que tenga el valor del title, si fuera php y en la pagina home.blade.php llamaría una variable $title_page="Home"; y en la etiqueta li algo asi:

```
<li class="<?php if ($title_page=="Home"){ echo "active"; } ?>">
  <a href="home.blade.php" >Home</a>
</li>
```

lo que necesito es capturar el contenido del blade que tengo en home.blade.php y evaluar lo para motivos del css

Comment: Sería más fácil si el título viniera en una variable, ¿es posible?

Comment: No se como hacer la en laravel, como la mando en @section('title')<br>
Home<br>
@endsection  ademas aplicacion.blade.php no es llamado en el PageController o en el web.config

Comment: ¿Por que estás incluyendo "<br>"? Deberías de pasarlo de esta forma `@section('title') Home @endsection`

Comment: Disulpen esos <br> fueron un error que puse para la publicación tomara espacios

Comment: No importa si esto se hace con javascript, ya que seria una forma mas simple de hacer lo que deseas.

Answer (score 3):

Para poder realizar el menú dinámico tienes que hacer uso de `Request::segment()`, sabiendo como esta constituido tu menú puedes realizar la verificación de los `segmentos` de la `url`.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php $segment = Request::segment(1); ?>
<li class="<?php if ($segment=="Home"){ echo "active"; } ?>">
  <a href="home.blade.php" >Home</a>
</li>
```

En la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests) de laravel puedes ver las formas de hacer uso de los segmentos de url, el numero indica el segmento que estas tomando.

Por ejemplo:

```
http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up
```

Los números de segmento serían estos:

1. news
2. local
3. metro
4. crime_is_up

Cabe mencionar que tienes que agregar `use Request;`.

Answer (score -2):

```
<title>NombreWeb|| @yield('title')</title>
```

En la parte de la base o plantilla

```
@section('title', 'Mtutituloaqui')
```

en la zona de la vista que quieres mostrar.